# Having no condition in for loop makes compiler fixes "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Why having no condition in for loop fixes not all code paths returns value. For example: **i < 3**. I know that this is bad practice/code.

Tested on .net6 and .netcore-2.1

Working examples:

```
// Code that does not return error "not all code paths return a value"
public class ThrowingExceptionTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Result Test()
    {
        for (int i =0; ; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = new Result(Name.Length);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (i < 3 && ex is NullReferenceException)
                    throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

vs

```
// Code that does returns error "not all code paths return a value"
public class ThrowingExceptionTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Result Test()
    {
        for (int i =0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = new Result(Name.Length);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (i < 3 && ex is NullReferenceException)
                    throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is an infinite loop. Since the loop will never exit, the case where the loop ends does not need to be handled. You could just have written

```
public int Test()
{
    while(true){} // No "not all code paths return a value" error
}
```

In your second example the constructor may for example throw `Exception` that causes the exception to be handled, but not re thrown. So eventually the loop may exit, so you need ensure some value is returned.  Simplified it turns into

```
public int Test()
{
    while(false){} 
    return 0; // will happen, must return a value
}
```

Note that the compiler is conservative, there will be cases where something cannot happen but the compiler cannot (or does not bother) to prove it. For example:

```
public int Test()
{
    var i = 0;
    if (i == 0)
        return 1;
   return 0;// will never happen, but is needed to avoid the error
}
```

The compiler *could* prove that the `return 0` will never be reached, but with my version of the compiler it still require the `return 0`, (a newer compiler might handle this case better).

Ofc, the whole example is nonsensical, so it is not really possible to suggest how it should be written.